# How to resolve database connection error to openfire

Tags: mysql, openfire

I have setup openfire on Linux machine, but when I try to configure this with standard database connection it shows following error connection
to the database could not be made but my database password is right for this I have also checked the error log
file but I don't get any important information.please help me to resolve this problem I am also attaching the screenshot for the above error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the port in the connection url to the port of your mysql server, it may not be 3306" it could be 3360 or other ports.

Comment: same error with 3360 and i think it takes mysql port and by default port of mysql is 3306.

Comment: Try to run this command in your terminal and use the shown port in your connection url: `netstat -tlpn | grep mysql`

Comment: Hi i have write this command and it gives no port number for mysql on my server from which i have to setup openfire but when i use this command on my local ubuntu machine its gives tcp6 3306 listen may be thats why openfire is not installing ?

Comment: if this is a error then you have any idea how mysql listen this port 3306 ?

Comment: Mysql isn't running.

Comment: But when i open phpmyadmin it is running well and i have also apply mysql operations.

Comment: So you can run mysql stuff on the openfire server?

Comment: Same problem with me. phpmyadmin working but can not connect with openfire

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow below steps to resolution it:

1. Change Database Driver Presets to Mysql (Or preferred database server.).
2. Database URL seems correct. As per your shared image, you should have a database with name "openfire".
3. Change Username and Password as your database configuration (Mysql).

It should resolve your problem. :)